# How to minimize and maximize in C#.Net?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to minimize and maximize manually in C#.net.
I changed form's BorderStyle into none.
So there are no maximize,minimize and close button from bar.
I want to manually create with button like those functions.
I want to do three functions in button click events.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You have to set the forms WindowState property something like this:

In Windows Forms:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
}
```

In WPF:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
}
```

Comment: Its doesn't change anything. ??

Answer (score 7):

Form.WindowState Property

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.windowstate%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

```
public FormWindowState WindowState { get; set; }
```

For example -

```
var form = new Form();
form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
```

However, if you are in the code behind on the main form (or any form) just do this -

```
WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using WindowsForms you have to change the WindowState property :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal) 
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        }
        else
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }
```

Comment: Never compare enums by its string representation if you can compare against the enum element directly! In this case the right way would be `if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)`.