# How to move form in C#.Net?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Thanks you for your previous answers for my question.
you can see following link.

[How to minimize and maximize in C#.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285386/how-to-minimize-and-maximize-in-c-net)

Now i'm facing another problem.
When i changed my form's borderstyle to none,i can't move form like the real form.
Its stable and can't move anywhere.

In Windows form's normal borderstyle can move anywhere.
But i want to move like that in borderstyle's none property.
How can i do that?
Please let me know if you can.
Thanks you for your time. :)

Answer (score 10):

```
public class AppFormBase : Form
{   
    public Point downPoint = Point.Empty;

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FormBorderStyle == System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None)
        {
            MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(AppFormBase_MouseDown);
            MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(AppFormBase_MouseMove);
            MouseUp   += new MouseEventHandler(AppFormBase_MouseUp);
        }

        base.OnLoad(e);
    }

    private void AppFormBase_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            downPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
    }
    private void AppFormBase_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (downPoint != Point.Empty)
            Location = new Point(Left + e.X - downPoint.X, Top + e.Y, - downPoint.Y);
    }
    private void AppFormBase_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            downPoint = Point.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer.  @Seven - if the "movable" form contains controls that you want to be able to grab with mouse as well, then you also need to handle those controls MouseMove/MouseDown/MouseUp events with the handlers Gabriel wrote.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/csharpmovewindow.aspx.

Here's the gist of it:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
public const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;

[DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
[DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();

private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{     
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        ReleaseCapture();
        SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
public const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;
private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Capture = false;
    Message msg = Message.Create(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, (IntPtr)HT_CAPTION, IntPtr.Zero);
base.WndProc(ref msg);
}
```